# Whisk that's made in china

Tags: equipment

I have a whisk that is probably made of metal, and it's made from China. I'm not sure if I should use it since it's red, and I don't know if it could be paint. Is there a way I could tell if it's safe to use? Because I'm afraid if it's paint it might fall of, which could be unsanitary.

Comment: Do you a picture...a point of purchase...a label?  Many, many items are safely made in China and imported into the US.

Comment: ...and Canada...

Comment: ... and Europe!  Actually all over the world except China! **;-)** @moscafj

Answer (score 1):

A whisk is cheap kitchen tool.

If unsure, just throw/recycle it away and get yourself a new one made from stainless steel wire.